# Contract call: MyContract#<unrecognized-selector>

Tags: solidity, react, smart-contract

new to solidity and I am trying to make a simple calculator DApp. I keep getting an error when I call my add function from the contract. It still performs the add function but in the console it gives the following error.

```
 eth_call
Contract call: Calculator#<unrecognized-selector> 
From: 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
To:   0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512
Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function at Calculator.<unrecognized-selector> (contracts/Calculator.sol:5)
```

I have similar function that that is called equals and it gets the results of the calculator and it does not give this error.

```
eth_blockNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_feeHistory
eth_call
  Contract call:       Calculator#equals
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512

eth_blockNumber
```

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? The following is my code:

CalculatorInterface.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "../style/Calculator.css";

const CalculatorInterface = ({ provider, account, calculator }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setInputValue(inputValue + event.target.textContent);
  };

  const math = async () => {
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const result = await calculator.connect(signer).add(inputValue);
    setInputValue(inputValue);
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(result);
  };

  const equals = async () => {
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const result = await calculator.connect(signer).equals();
    setInputValue(result);
    console.log(result);
  };

  return (
    <div className="calculator-body">
      <input
        className="calculator-input"
        type="text"
        id="input"
        value={inputValue}
        readOnly
      />
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        1
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        2
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        3
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        4
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        5
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        6
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        7
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        8
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        9
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        0
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={equals}>
        =
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={() => setInputValue("")}>
        CLR
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={math}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        -
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        *
      </button>
      <button className="calculator-key" onClick={handleClick}>
        /
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CalculatorInterface;
```

Calculator.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;


contract Calculator {
    // Set to 25 for testing 
    int256 public result;

    function equals() public view returns (int256) {
        return result;
    }

    function clear() public returns (int256) {
        return result = 0;
    }

    function add(int256 _num) public returns (int256) {
        return result = result + _num;
    }

    function subtract(int256 _num) public returns (int256) {
        return result = result - _num;
    }

    function multiply(int256 _num) public returns (int256) {
        return result = result * _num;
    }

    function divide(int256 _num) public returns (int256) {
        return result = result / _num;
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the root of your problem, but you set the input value to be an empty string on initialization. You should've set it to 0 instead.

Comment: I changed it to 0 but still experiencing the same issue.